# Rspec for routes using advanced constraint on querystring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

In my Rails app, I needed a really fast way to block requests that contain specific query string values. I was able to do this in routes using advanced constraints. It works great in the real world, but I can't figure out how to write a test for it.

Here's the code from my routes.rb:

```
class BlockedConstraint
  @@block_ids = []
  @@block_ids << '12345'
  @@block_ids << '67890'
  def self.matches?(request)
    @@block_ids.include?(request.query_parameters["app_id"])
  end
end

namespace :api do
  match "*path" => "block#block_request", :constraints => BlockedConstraint
  match 'ads' => 'status#get_status', :via => :get
  match 'init' => 'init#get_init', :via => :get
  #etc.
end
```

Here's my spec:

```
describe "BlockController" do
  it "blocks app_id 12345" do
    { :get => 'api/status', :app_id => '12345' }.should route_to(
      :controller => 'api/block',
      :action => 'block_request'
    )
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: { :get => 'api/status', :app_id => '12345' }.should route_to(
Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError:
   The recognized options <{"action"=>"get_status", "controller"=>"api/status"}> did not match <{"action"=>"block_request", "controller"=>"api/block"}>, difference: <{"action"=>"block_request", "controller"=>"api/block"}>
```

I also tried it in routing/routes_spec.rb, with describe Routing. Same result. (I'm actually not sure if it's best to put it with routing specs or controller specs.)

I'm running Rails 3.0.10 and Rspec 2.11.0.

Comment: Try your routing spec with the app_id baked into the path, e.g. `{ :get => 'api/status?appid=12345' }`

Comment: That gives me the same error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested constraints before using route_to tests but may be anonymous controller could be useful for your test.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

You could write spec for application controller like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def index
    end
  end

  describe 'handling block constraints' do
    before { get :index, :app_id => '100' }

    it "should block request" do
      should redirect_to(:controller => 'blocks', :action => 'block_request')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI all, @oivoodoo and I both tried this and it's not working. Any other ideas anyone?